# Removing time from date for an entire data stored in an array

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime

Using Excel VBA, how would I apply the formula `Date(year(A1),Month(A1),Day(A1))` to all the dates in an entire column? Currently the data is in date time format (e.g. 30/04/1995  9:35:00 AM) but I want just the date - 30/04/1995.

Currently all of the dates are stored in an array and I have tried `Columns(data_column).NumberFormat = "[$-1009]d-mmm-yy;@"`,
but I have not been successful in removing the time from the dates.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in VBA instead of just typing the formula into a cell and dragging down the formula?  I am confused because the first paragraph says you want to apply this to dates in a column, yet the second says the dates are stored in an array.  Is there pre-existing VBA code that you are using?

Comment: yes there is a pre-exiting VBA code I am using. Otherwise I would simply just use the formulas, but I cannot modify the original database.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to change the display format of your data while preserving the time information, you can use something like NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" in cells of a worksheet or chart axis.

Excel stores date/time info as a floating point number. The days are to the left of the decimal and fractions of days (hh:mm:ss) are to the right. If you want to strip out the time information from the underlying data, then convert to Long then back to Date. In VBA (thanks to T.M. for the correction):

```
DateOnly = CDate(Int(DateTime))
```

In worksheet formulas just convert to Int and format as you please

```
DateOnly = INT(DateTime)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: (Late) side note :-) Consider that  the `CLng` function **rounds up** to next day *all* afternoon hours after midday which possibly  returns unwanted results.  So it's perfectly okay to use  *VBA*'s `Int`  or `Fix` function in  code lines: `DateOnly = CDate(Int(DateTime))` @xidgel

Answer (score 3):

All dates in Excel include time: datetime. It is not possible to store a date only or a time only in a cell. The reason is that Excel stores them as numbers. Anything before the decimal point is the date and anything after the decimal point is the time. So, even if you put the number 42000 in a cell (without anything after the decimal point) and change the format of that cell to date, the value will still be December 27, 2014 (42000 days after December 31, 1899) with an assumed time of zero = 00:00:00 in the morning.

Since all numbers can potentially have something after the decimal point, all dates have time in Excel and all times have dates.

The only thing you can do is: format a cell to show only the date part or the time part or both. So, all you need to do is to hide the time.

If you want to change all dates to have zero after the decimal point then you'll have to loop through the numbers and change all values to INT values.

```
For intColumn = 1 to 1000
   If Sheet1.Cells(1, intColumn).Value2 = vbNullString then Exit For
   Sheet1.Cells(1, intColumn).Value2 = Int(Sheet1.Cells(1, intColumn).Value2) ' Do not use CInt but Int only!
next intColumn
```

Comment: How would I hide the time or make it zero?

Comment: @absundo: change the format of the cell using `.NumberFormat`. If you don't know which format you want, then just right-click on a cell, format it to Date, click OK and then go into VBA and write into the direct window:
`? Selection.NumberFormat`That's the format you want to apply.

Comment: Change the formatting to Text or General. Add a formula. Then VBA to copy cell and paste values. =YEAR(K11)&"-"&RIGHT("0"&MONTH(K11),2) & "-" & RIGHT("0"&DAY(K11),2) ..... Then Range("F7").Copy .... Then Select cell..... Then paste just value w/o time. Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Answer (score 1):

**Removing time from date for an entire data stored in an array**

IMO this question rather asks how to change values *directly in an array* containing *dates* including time indications.
Therefore I the following example code just as an addition to the valid solutions above demonstrating how to

- get a zero-based 1-dim array from a data column (without loops),
- execute the time removals (in a Loop) using *VBA*'s `Fix` function *) to cut the decimal part of the date value and
- (optionally write back the array to any wanted column)

*) Using the `CLng` instead of `Fix`(or `Int`) would round up to the next day any dates with afternoon hours after midday.

**Example code**

Assumes date values e.g. in column `B:B` (omitting a title row).

```
Sub chngDateArray()
  Dim ws As Worksheet  
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")                             ' << change to your sheet name string
  Dim lastRow&, i&, arr
  lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     
' [1a] assign dates to (1-based) 2-dim datafield array
       arr = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Value2                                ' get date values as numbers
' [1b] rearrange to (0-based) 1-dim array
       arr = Application.Transpose(arr): ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) -1) ' make it a "flat" (zero-based) array
' [2]  eliminate time portions and reconvert to date
       For i = 0 To UBound(arr)    
           arr(i) = CDate(Fix(arr(i)))                                        ' cut time portions from entire dates
       Next i
       ' Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")                                           ' check in immediate window

' [3]  {optional}: write back array to any wanted column (e.g. D:D)
       ws.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

**Additional note**

Using `.Value2` in section `[1a]` allows to get dates as numbers only. The reconversion to date format in section `[2]` eventually allows to write back the array data to any wanted column in section `[3]` *without prior column formatting* via `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, you should also be able to pull just the date from those strings using either `DateValue()` or `Format()` like so:

```
DateValue("30/04/1995 9:35:00 AM")
Format("30/04/1995 9:35:00 AM", "dd/mm/yyyy")
```